# Insert QuerySet results in a table in Django

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-queryset, django-orm

I have a queryset and I want to insert the results of that queryset into a database table (say `SelectedFeatures`).

```
all_features = Feature.objects.filter(product_id = selected_product_id)
```

The structure of the new table and the `Feature` table would almost be the same except one field. Should I just insert all the fields of the queryset manually like inserting records into a table or is there another way to cater this?

Answer (score 1):

I like @doniyor's solution but if you need more control (for example if field names aren't exactly the same) you could iterate over the fields and possibly make some decisions:

```
for feature in Feature.objects.filter(product_id = selected_product_id).all():
    selected_feature = SelectedFeature()
    for attr in SelectedFeature._meta.get_all_field_names():
         selected_feature.setattr(attr, feature.getattr(attr))
    selected_feature.save()
```